# format DateTime with text in-between

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting, string-concatenation

I want to format my DateTime object in a specific way. This is the basis:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2018, 11, 20, 15, 30, 5, 0);
Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

The output will be `Tue Nov 20 15:30:05 +01:00 2018`. This is ALMOST what I want: instead of the `+01:00` I want the value of a `string` variable `myText`.

So if `myText` has the value `"hello world"`, the output should be:

`Tue Nov 20 15:30:05 hello world 2018`

So my question is simply: **What do I need to write to get formatting** (except the `zzz` part) **but with the value of a `string` variable in-between?**

I tried `dt.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss " + myText + " yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, but for `myText = "hello world"` it will output

`Tue Nov 20 15:30:05 3ello worl20 2018`

i.e. the content of `myText` will be considered as formatting, just as the rest. But I want the content of `myText` to be taken literally instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap your text in quotes (`'`) and it will output your desired format.

```
dt.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss '" + myText + "' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// output
Tue Apr 02 12:37:49 hello world 2019
```

It's matching the `h` from `hello` and the `d` from `world` which is why you were seeing that result.

You may look at [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals) from microsoft which has a section (near the bottom) regarding quotation marks.  The inclusion of quotes (either single `'` or double `"`) in a DateTime format (or Numeric format) introduces a string literal in the resulting string format.

As @Dmitry points out in a comment, you may need to use `myText?.Replace("'", "''")` if `'` appear in your string.  Another option is to use double quotes and escape as usual:

```
dt.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"" + myText + "\" yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `+ myText?.Replace("'", "''") +` in order to *escape* `'` if they appear in `myText` for the  solution be perfect.

Comment: You can also just escape the formatting characters:  `dt.ToString(@"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \Hello Worl\d yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` although this is a bit inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to do this with multiple lines? I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2018, 11, 20, 15, 30, 5, 0);
string x = (dt.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss X yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
string z = x.Replace("X", "myText");
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

We put an "X" in our dt.ToString() because an "X" won't be formatted, and will serve as our placeholder to replace the value of with whatever custom text we want after the date is formatted.